# increase multiple rows based on minimum and maximum of age for each id in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have this data set:

[image]

Now I want to add rows, which contain all the ages that between minimum and maximum of each id, like this dataset:

[image]

Could someone give me some tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks a lot for your reply. I add a column to combine min_age and max_age using paste(data$MinAGE, data$MaxAGE, sep=","), and then add only one row (maxium age) for each id using separate_rows function. What I need is to add multiple rows for all ages of each id.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `data.table`

```
DF <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                 min_age = c(60, 55, 72, 67, 58),
                 max_age = c(65, 57, 72, 69, 61))

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, .(age = seq(min_age, max_age)), by = id]
#    id age
# 1:  1  60
# 2:  1  61
# 3:  1  62
# 4:  1  63
# 5:  1  64
# 6:  1  65
# 7:  2  55
# 8:  2  56
# 9:  2  57
#10:  3  72
#11:  4  67
#12:  4  68
#13:  4  69
#14:  5  58
#15:  5  59
#16:  5  60
#17:  5  61
```

Comment: Wow, I tried it just now. I worked well! Thanks so much markus!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  We get the sequence of 'min_age', 'max_age' with `map2` within `transmute` and then `unnest` the `list` column to get the expected output

```
library(tidyverse)
DF  %>% 
   transmute(id = id, age = map2(min_age, max_age, `:`)) %>%
   unnest
#   id age
#1   1  60
#2   1  61
#3   1  62
#4   1  63
#5   1  64
#6   1  65
#7   2  55
#8   2  56
#9   2  57
#10  3  72
#11  4  67
#12  4  68
#13  4  69
#14  5  58
#15  5  59
#16  5  60
#17  5  61
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Map`

```
stack(setNames(do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, DF[-1])), DF$id))[2:1]
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(id = 1:5, min_age = c(60, 55, 72, 67, 58), max_age = c(65, 
 57, 72, 69, 61)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
 ))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, I tried your suggestions too. It also worked well. Thanks so much for your help!